# Javascript Calculator JS - Switch Case

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the case is not working

```
var a, b;

a = 0;
b = 0


function Calculatrice(a, b, op) {

  switch (op) {

    alert("Choisissez votre opérateur: ");

    case '+':
      return a + b
      break;
    case '-':
      return a - b
      break;
    case '*':
      return a * b
      break;
    case '/':
      return a / b
      break;

      alert("Voici la valeur finale:");
  }

}

Calculatrice(5, 5, +);
```

Comment: try with this `Calculatrice(5,5,'+');`

Comment: You should always check your browser console for error messages. You can't run commands like `alert()` inside a switch block. And you're checking for `'+'`, not `+` (which is invalid on its own).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and these are the changes done to your code for proper result :
 1. Your switch statement had dangling alerts in between, which were not
    required.
 2. I removed your global variables `a,b` because that is not required
    in the current function scope.
 3. You should pass the operation as `string`, as that is what is
    expected in the switch statement.

Here is your working code.

```js
function Calculatrice(a, b, op) {

  switch (op) {

    case '+':
      return a + b
      break;
    case '-':
      return a - b
      break;
    case '*':
      return a * b
      break;
    case '/':
      return a / b
      break;
  
  }

}
console.log(Calculatrice(5, 5, '+'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a, b;

a = 0;
b = 0


function Calculatrice(a, b, op) {
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      return a + b
    case '-':
      return a - b
    case '*':
      return a * b
    case '/':
      return a / b
    default: 
      return "invalid arguments"
  }
}

var result = Calculatrice(5, 5, '+');
console.log("Voici la valeur finale: ", result);
var result = Calculatrice(5, 5, '-');
console.log("Voici la valeur finale: ", result);
var result = Calculatrice(5, 5, '*');
console.log("Voici la valeur finale: ", result);
var result = Calculatrice(5, 5, '/');
console.log("Voici la valeur finale: ", result);
var result = Calculatrice(5, 5, '%');
console.log("Voici la valeur finale: ", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `alert` of body of `switch`
2. use of `'+'` instead of `+`, when call `Calculatrice` function.

**If you want to get the operator from the user,use `prompt()` like this:**

```js
function Calculatrice(a, b, op) {
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      return a + b
      break;
    case '-':
      return a - b
      break;
    case '*':
      return a * b
      break;
    case '/':
      return a / b
      break;
  }
}

op = prompt('Choisissez votre opérateur [ + - / * ] :');
var operators = ['+','-','/','*'];

if ( operators.indexOf(op) !== -1 )
  alert('Voici la valeur finale: ' + Calculatrice(5, 5, op) ) ;
else
  alert("L'opérateur est mal!");
```